# MySQL join, count and group by multiple database

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, left-join

I have this working query

```
SELECT t1.id as stockid, t1.description as stockdescription, t2.inkoop as price , COUNT(t2.inkoop) as cnt, 
(t2.inkoop *  COUNT(t2.inkoop)) as totalamount
FROM database1.table_products t1 
LEFT JOIN database1.table_stock t2 ON t1.id = t2.stock_id 
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY t2.inkoop
ORDER BY t1.id ASC
```

1 database, 2 tables:
t1 is the products 'description' database with ids and description
t2 is the stock, which has a lot of products for what price (purchased) and referenced by stock_id

```
Output:
id  stockdescription   price cnt totalamount
1   Product1           1067  15  16005
1   Product1           1290 103  132870
2   Product2           2750  70  192500
3   Product3           500    0  0
```

But now i have this 2nd database (database2) with a second inventory table (stock2) (exactly the same structure as database1.table_stock)

How do i alter my query so i can also add 'cnt2' and change total to my results?

```
Like this:
id  stockdescription   price cnt cnt2 totalcnt totalamount
1   Product1           1067  15   0    15      16005
1   Product1           1290 103   0    103     132870
2   Product2           2750  70   5    75      206250
3   Product3           500    0   4     4      2000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join multiple tables, but you'd get the full join of the two stock tables, which means you'd get wrong counts after the `GROUP BY`. You can avoid that by nesting your queries, e.g. along these lines:

```
SELECT sub.*, COUNT(stock2.inkoop) AS cnt2
FROM ( <paste your query here> ) AS sub
LEFT JOIN database2.stock2 AS stock2 ON sub.stockid = stock2.stock_id
GROUP BY sub.stockid
ORDER BY sub.stockid ASC
```

Now you have two left joins, each with its own `GROUP BY`. So each left join only sees a single left hand table factor, and you won't get duplicates caused by joining too many tables at once.